# Android Uneven Design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have an element that should remain centered in the layout and a button on the right size. The button width is variable.

The following design exemplify two scenarios.

**Scenario 1: Long text button**
[image: scenario 1]
**Scenario 2: Small text button**
[image: scenario_2]

The current solution is have an invisible duplicated button on the left. This is not ideal because the button look and feel may also vary for different locales. I have tried guidelines but that would require to define a percentage and I would prefer if it was dynamic. Barriers don't seem to work either because I would need them to be mirrored.

Any tips how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see how this relates. Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing width with 0dp and give them weight and change this in runtime
may be they are in linear layout which is horizontal.

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)   
  button.getLayoutParams();
  params.weight = 1.0f; // afterwards you can do the same with changing the weight
  button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I would rather avoid runtime changes if possible. Ideally it would all done in xml. I'll give this a go if there are no other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can take advantage of the ConstraintLayoutStates:
https://riggaroo.co.za/constraintlayout-constraintlayoutstates/

And have two layouts one for each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a different solution. I used two guidelines, one at 20% and another at 80%, to define the areas where the button could expand to.

[image]

When no button is available, I used the property `app:layout_constrainedWidth="false"` that ignores the constrainst and allow the title to expand to the available space.

[image]

I used this solution because I may need multiple buttons with different call to actions according to the selected language. It would be difficult to manage multiple hidden anchor buttons.

Comment: Interesting. How does it look on the xml?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your pictures correctly, you want to have two elements on your screen:

1. A View that's centered on the screen, it can be any width size.
2. A Button that's positioned to the right of the View that can also be any width size. You want this button to be centered in the empty space between the View and the edge of the right screen.

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="2"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Not exactly.
I want the view to reduce it's size when the button text is longer. I don't want the button to occupy only the available space left by the text view. I want the text view to shrink but still be centered.

I can make the view move to left when the button text grows but will no longer be centered. Hence my problem. How to keep the same space occupied by the button on the left side of the screen so the view is centered.

Comment: There's nothing you can do besides using an INVISIBLE matching view on the opposite side and create a horizontal chain. This is because to allow the center View to shrink, it's width must be set to '0dp'. But by doing so, it definitely needs restraints to match against on the opposite side if you wish for it to remain in the center. Honestly, you won't sacrifice much through using an invisible button.

Comment: That's my current solution. I asked the question to see if someone knew some weird black magic that could handle this cases. 
Also the problem with the hidden button is that I don't have only "one button". It started with one button for a specific country, now for another country there will be another button with animation and I don't even know what can come tomorrow. Thanks for you feedback. You answers is the one I prefer so far and increases my confidence in the my current solution.